# how to get location in android using network(wi-fi)?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I tried a lot of stuff like:

```
location = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

but the location is always set to `null`.

Comment: would you post your code?

Comment: Right, post your manifest permissions and all the content that relates to getting position updates, e.g. registering the `LocationManagaer` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are couple of code snippet those would be useful:

```
private void _getLocation() {

    // Get the location manager
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) 
            getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Double longitude, latitude;
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

    try {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        latitude = -1.0;
        longitude = -1.0;
    }
}
```

This might however request a FINE_LOCATION access. So you would need to add following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

The quickest possible way is to use the Last Known location with this, I used it and it's quite fast:

```
private double[] getGPS() {
 LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(
 Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
 List<String> providers = lm.getProviders(true);

 Location location = null;

 for (int i=providers.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
     location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(i));
     if (location != null) 
         break;
 }

 double[] gps = new double[2];
 if (location != null) {
     gps[0] = location.getLatitude();
     gps[1] = location.getLongitude();
 }

 return gps;
}
```

You also might want to refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) developers guide for LocationManager.

FYI: don't forget to add following permissions according to the method you use.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: You can get away without android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION will use the mobile network + wifi (if enabled on the device).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following permissions to your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```